# How to convert datatable to json string in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, json

Its work perfect when data in the datatable is small i.e 10 columns and 300 rows. But when the amount of data in datatable is large it did not work.
Here is my code

```
[WebMethod]

public static string getData()
{
    string _cs = "";
    string _query = "";
    OleDbConnection _conn = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbCommand _cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataAdapter _da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataTable _dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        _cs = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + _path + ";Extended Properties=  \"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";";
        //_query = "SELECT * FROM [3123121288$A1:L290]";  work perfect
        _query = "SELECT * FROM [3123121288$]";         //did not work
        _conn.ConnectionString = _cs;
        _cmd.Connection = _conn;
        _cmd.CommandText = _query;
        _da.SelectCommand = _cmd;
        _da.Fill(_dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_dt);
}
```

Comment: What does "did not work" mean. I have no idea what you mean by that. What did you expect to happen, and what actually happened? And why do you have an empty catch block? You should almost never have one of those.

Comment: its only convert less than 300 rows and can't covert more than 300 rows. it just trim the rows that are more than 300

Comment: So you're saying it removes the rows from the output if there's more than 300 rows? That would have been good to say in your question. Did you inspect `_dt` in your IDE's debugger to see if it has all the rows?

Comment: yes i debug _dt it have all the rows

Comment: I've created a sample DataTable with 555 rows to test your assertation, that not all rows being serialized. And I cannot reproduced that. All rows are in that generated json.

Comment: then why the hell I can't get JSON in javascript. basically this is a web method that I am caling in my javascript